# Problems getting the id from the result

Tags: coldfusion

I'm returning 2 results from a stored proc and trying to display a logo if one of them has badgeid 2. They have a badge id column with values of 1 and 2. I'm trying to do this but it won't work:

```
<cfif qBadges.badgeid EQ 2>
 logo here
</cfif>
```

If I change it to 1 it will show the old logo. 2 is a new logo I just added. Thanks!

**Edit**

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="sel_MemberBadges_p" datasource="DSN">
        <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ID#">
        <cfprocresult name="qBadges">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfif qBadges.badgeid EQ 2>
         new logo here
<cfelseif qBadges.badgeid EQ 1>
         old logo
</cfif>
```

Comment: probably be more helpful if you posted the cfstoredproc cod and the SP.

Comment: Added more code. The stored proc returns just two results. #1 and #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
<cfif qBadges.badgeid[1] EQ 2>
    new logo here
<cfelseif qBadges.badgeid[2] EQ 1>
     old logo
</cfif>
```

It is because unless you specify what row you want it will return the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping out the result so you can see the badge id values:

```
 <cfstoredproc procedure="sel_MemberBadges_p" datasource="DSN">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#ID#">
    <cfprocresult name="qBadges">
  </cfstoredproc>
<cfdump var="#qBadges#" />
<cfabort />
<cfif qBadges.badgeid EQ 2>
     new logo here
<cfelseif qBadges.badgeid EQ 1>
     old logo
</cfif>
```